# Tensorflow Incompatible return types from tf.cond

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm hoping someone can help me debug a quick error I'm facing.

```
def _examples(file_name_queue, reader, num_threads, read_batch_size):

  with ops.name_scope('read'):
    for _ in range(num_threads):
      keys, values = tf.cond(
          math_ops.less(1, read_batch_size),
          lambda: reader().read_up_to(file_name_queue, read_batch_size),
          lambda: reader().read(file_name_queue)
      )
# More after this but dropping for brevity.
```

However I'm getting the below error that appears to be from true_fn and false_fn in tf.cond not coming from the same class.

> TypeError: Incompatible return types of true_fn and false_fn: The two
>   structures don't have the same sequence type. First structure has type
>   , while second
>   structure has type .

What is the best way to resolve an issue like this? Is there a way to cast these classes, rewrite true_fn/false_fn, or some other way to modify the lambdas to unify the sequence types?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), you will get this description:

true_fn and false_fn both return lists of output tensors. true_fn and false_fn must have the **same** non-zero number and **type of outputs**.

Now let's look into the documentation of [TFRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader)
These are the return types of the following functions:

[`read_up_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader#read_up_to): A tuple of Tensors (keys, values). keys: A 1-D string Tensor. values: A 1-D string Tensor.

[`read`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader#read): A tuple of Tensors (key, value). key: A string scalar Tensor. value: A string scalar Tensor.

To give further explanation, you will have to give more amount of code, but the concept of mistake has been highlighted.

Comment: Many thanks. This gives me a good lead on where to start looking.